# android - radioButton return id

Tags: java, android

In my app I have a fragment with a radioGroup including three radioButtons. I set an ID to every radioButton and after a button is clicked I want to pass the selected id to a textView. Right now it returns the value -1 every time, so like no button is selected. Why doesn‘t it return the correct value?

My code:

```
public class ItemThreeFragment extends Fragment {

    TextView testText;
    int x;

    public static ItemThreeFragment newInstance() {
        ItemThreeFragment fragment = new ItemThreeFragment();
        return fragment;
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    }

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                             Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_item_three, container, false);

        final int rb1id = 0;
        final int rb2id = 1;
        final int rb3id = 2;

        final RadioGroup rg = (RadioGroup) getActivity().findViewById(R.id.RGroup);
        RadioButton rb1 = (RadioButton) getActivity().findViewById(R.id.radioButton);
        RadioButton rb2 = (RadioButton) getActivity().findViewById(R.id.radioButton2);
        RadioButton rb3 = (RadioButton) getActivity().findViewById(R.id.radioButton3);

        rb1.setId(rb1id);
        rb2.setId(rb2id);
        rb3.setId(rb3id);

        Button button = (Button) view.findViewById(R.id.button);
        button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {

                x = rg.getCheckedRadioButtonId();
                testText = getActivity().findViewById(R.id.textView5);
                testText.setText(String.valueOf(x));

            }
        });

        return view;
    }

}
```

The xml code:

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <RadioGroup
        android:id="@+id/RGroup"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@+id/textView"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:orientation="horizontal">

        <RadioButton
            android:id="@+id/radioButton2"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_below="@+id/textView"
            android:layout_marginRight="30dp"
            android:layout_toLeftOf="@id/radioButton"
            android:text="E5" />

        <RadioButton
            android:id="@+id/radioButton"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_below="@+id/textView"
            android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
            android:text="E10" />

        <RadioButton
            android:id="@+id/radioButton3"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignTop="@+id/radioButton"
            android:layout_marginLeft="30dp"
            android:layout_toEndOf="@+id/radioButton"
            android:layout_toRightOf="@id/radioButton"
            android:text="Diesel" />
    </RadioGroup>


    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@+id/textView11"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:onClick="onClick"
        android:text="Button" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView5"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@+id/button"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:text="TextView" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: What exactly are you doing? You give new ids to views that already have ids? rb1 has id R.id.radioButton, rb2 has id R.id.radioButton2 and rb3 has id R.id.radioButton3. You don't need setId.

Comment: Good point! But that’s not the issue, I struggle with the returned value

Comment: Remove the new ids and try again

Comment: I did, still the same problem: seems like no button is selected

Comment: Are you sure that one of the radio buttons is checked before you click the button? Beacause -1 means nothing is checked.

Comment: Also are you sure that these 3 radio buttons are inside the radiogroup?

Comment: @user9582784 are you sure RadioButton's are inside activity's xml file ?

Comment: @mTak Is it necessary to have one selected as default? They are in the radiogroup, yes

Comment: @Shijil no, they aren’t. They are in the corresponding layout of my fragment class

Comment: It is necessary to have one selected before you click the button. Otherwise you get -1.

Comment: @mTak when I do that, I always get the value of the one I checked. I get it working in a normal activity, but in my fragment it doesn’t work..

Comment: Can you paste fragment_item_three.xml?

Comment: @mTak yes sure, I added it!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try this one...

```
...

final RadioGroup rg = (RadioGroup) view.findViewById(R.id.RGroup);

RadioButton rb1 = (RadioButton) view.findViewById(R.id.radioButton);
RadioButton rb2 = (RadioButton) view.findViewById(R.id.radioButton2);
RadioButton rb3 = (RadioButton) view.findViewById(R.id.radioButton3);

...
```

Answer (score 0):

> You need to use setOnCheckedChangeListener on RadioGroup as Follow instead of Button click event.

```
public class ItemThreeFragment extends Fragment {

TextView testText;
int x;

public static ItemThreeFragment newInstance() {
    ItemThreeFragment fragment = new ItemThreeFragment();
    return fragment;
}

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    testText = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.textView5);
}

@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                         Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_item_three, container, false);


    final RadioGroup rg = (RadioGroup) getActivity().findViewById(R.id.RGroup);

    rg .setOnCheckedChangeListener(new OnCheckedChangeListener() 
    {
    @Override
    public void onCheckedChanged(RadioGroup group, int checkedId) {
       x = checkedId;
       testText.setText(x.toString());
    }
});

    return view;
}

}
```

Comment: Like that the textView doesn’t return anything. Do you have a suggestion what’s wrong?

Comment: I tried it with you edited answer, but the textView still doesn’t change, but I think it’s on the right track

Answer (score -1):

Get selected radio button from radioGroup plz try with this it's working for me.

```
        int selectedId = radioGroup.getCheckedRadioButtonId();

        // find the radiobutton by returned id
   RadioButton radioButton = (RadioButton) findViewById(selectedId);

        Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this,
            radioButton.getText(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
```

Comment: Would you put in in the context please? I have no radioButton defined as  ‘radioButton‘ defined, which would it be then?